# Is it possible to extend the timeout of 524 timeout cloud-fare using php?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on an existing application which is developed in wordpress.In that there is an task of exporting the data into the CSV file through ajax.Over there sometimes data is not exported into the CSV because the data process time become longer and HTTP response time limit is over so in response i am getting an error of "Error 524 A timeout occurred".So is it possible to extend the 524 timeout limit of cloudfare through PHP?